# check if image is accessable

Tags: php, mysql, image

i  got  image url saved in my database.i am using php and mysql.

Some images can be displayed but others are restricted.At the moment restricted image show up broken on my site.

I only which to display  non restricted images.

url for image that can be shown is
http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery/16678932_9061.jpg

restricted image is

http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery/8622798_7908.jpg

i have tried getimagesize but cant seem to be having any luck.

kind regards

nafri

Comment: get_headers() is an easy apprach

Comment: `if (file_exists...`.

Comment: Check the HTTP result code, if it's `HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden` then don't display it.

Comment: i will try get headers. i have tried file_exist and it doesn't work..

Comment: with getheaders i get this  Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Date] => Mon, 11 Nov 2013 23:13:17 GMT [Server] => Apache [Last-Modified] => Sat, 10 Mar 2012 17:50:24 GMT [Content-Length] => 3672 [Connection] => close [Content-Type] => image/jpeg )

Comment: 0 tells you its ok, see what you get for the fobidden file, then use that

Answer (score 1):

`file_exists()` doesn't work across domains. Server side can be done like:

```
$url = 'http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery/16678932_9061.jpg';
$header = get_headers($url, 1);
if(strpos( $header[0],'200') === false){
  // do what ever
}
```

EDIT: fixed for `200` response. Better use curl though, faster it is

Comment: I dont get 404 for forbidden images.. i get HTTP/1.1 200

Comment: this wont work as i get HTTP/1.1 200  for non forbidden  images as well.

Comment: I tried the restricted image from your example (Using IE) and I get 403, not 200.

Comment: i am using print_r(get_headers($url, 1)); and i get a response of 200

Comment: @naf, this answer is correct. maybe you are using the other correct $url so it responds as 200?

Comment: i am using this code to test it..<?php
$url = 'http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery/8622798_7908.jpg';
print_r(get_headers($url, 1));
?>

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to handle this on the client side, then you could use javascript to deal with this:

You can use handle the onError event to replace the image or do something else in the event that the image cannot be displayed.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/92819/637617) for an example.